# Is there a difference between the pronunciation of long-ass and long gas?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, homophones, fast-speech-rules

I know that final -⟨ng⟩ is pronounced /ŋ/ (in most dialects), but I'm wondering what happens when the intensifier "ass" comes after the /ŋ/ sound of "long". Does the pronunciation of "long-ass" become /lɑŋgæs/? Or does it stay like /lɑŋæs/? e.g. Do "long-ass" and "long gas" sound exactly the same?

Comment: Different accents have different pronunciations. Which in particular are you asking about?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm looking specifically for answers about GenAm, but I'd also like to know how they (/ŋ/ sounds) function in RP.

Comment: Well of course, a speaker of RP would never use a word like *ass* (which they would spell and pronounce as *arse* anyway in this context)! But the same applies to *sing* and *singer* where the *g* in the middle can go both ways.

Comment: On Lawn Giland, I believe, the pronunciation in either case would be "lawn gas."

Comment: Well, I use a moderate RP (i.e. not the very 'posh' kind) and I would pronounce 'long gas' as two distinct words; but some speakers of BrE pronounce a final 'g' on words ending in 'ng'.

Comment: In American English we would probably pronounce "long gas" as two distinct words. With "long-ass", however, there is only the /ŋ/ sound.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The combination of /ŋ/ and g afterwards seems to be the question. So to extend your example, how would one pronounce the two adjacent g's in "let's sing Gaslighter, by The Chicks"? I've never said that particular sentence myself, but my American instinct tells me to make an explicit "g" sound for the Gas in Gaslighter.

Comment: is long gas even a thing? When I google it, the only examples I find are company names.

Comment: @Barmar if you want a more relateable example, compare "long-ass tube" and "long gas tube"

Comment: @Jafar That makes sense, but since "gas tube" is a thing, there will likely be an extra pause before it.

Comment: @Brandin are you suggesting that the *g* is pronounced twice, with a glottal stop?

Comment: @djs I'm not sure if it's really a glottal stop; it feels more in the front of my mouth than that; I think a glottal stop is further back, almost in the throat. In phonetics I believe it is called a voiced /g/. So personally, if I said this, I would pronounce the *g* in 'gas' in "long gas" exactly the same way as the *g* in the phrase "out of gas" or "some gas" or "the gas" and so on. So, for "long gas", it would be a /ŋ/ followed by a voiced /g/ right after it.

Comment: @Barmar A long gas would be the opposite of a short gas. I doubt if either is really a common or idiomatic phrase on its own. *A gas* sometimes refers to one instance of flatulence ("to pass gas"), so in that context, a short one or long one would describe the duration of the activity.

Comment: @Brandin That would be a "long fart". While "pass gas" is a synonym for the verb "fart", I've never heard "gas" used as a synonym for the noun. You can "have gas", which means an upset stomach, which will then cause you to "pass gas" (or worse).

Comment: All you seem to be asking is whether words in collision can ever turn a final /ŋ/ followed by a vowel in the next word into /ŋg/—as in the *singer–finger* distinction. But you’ve used rather crude language to do so when you didn’t have to. You could make this question use inoffensive language by editing to ask about if anyone ever pronounces ***Long Island*** the same as they pronounce something like ***lawn guy land***.  That particular example comes with real-word examples (and counterexamples, depending on the dialect) that I trust you will find to be surprisingly well documented.

Comment: @tchrist well, to me using ass as a modifier is fairly normal, maybe even acceptable in a kindergarten. but regardless, yeah, I should've just asked what happens to final -⟨ng⟩ before a vowel. I'm not sure what to do now though about deleting the question or editing it or whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a difference; one has a /ɡ/ after the /ŋ/, and the other doesn't.

English has a set of velar phonemes (produced way back in the mouth, using the back of the tongue and the soft palate as articulators), including /k ɡ ŋ/. The velar nasal /ŋ/ frequently occurs alone, as in *singer*, and the homorganic nasal cluster /ŋɡ/ also occurs, as in *hunger*. Leaving out the /ɡ/ in *hunger* is wrong, and leaving it in *singer* is also wrong.

And things get messy at the end of the morpheme. Long ago, English had a rule that deleted voiced stops from certain final nasal + stop clusters, leaving silent letters in the ancient spellings, like *thumb, numb, dumb, sing, thing, long*. The "g" isn't really gone, because as usual the nasal has assimilated from dental /n/ to velar /ŋ/ because of that lost velar /ɡ/.

So, mostly, /ŋɡ/ doesn't occur finally; however, when things get added after it, the /ɡ/ could reappear after the /ŋ/, as in *longer* 'more long' -- that /ɡ/ has to be there. But there is another *-er* suffix in English, beside the comparative *-er* of *longer*; the *-er* of *worker* is called an "agentive suffix" -- it marks the actor (aka "agent") of the root verb. There is also another word *long*, which is a verb meaning "suffer distress from unfulfilled desire" and takes a preposition *for* to indicate the missing object of desire.

This leads to two words with different clusters

- *longer* Adj, comparative form of adj *long*, pronounced /'lɔŋɡər/ (**with** /ɡ/)
- *longer* Noun, agentive form of vb *long*, pronounced /'lɔŋər/  (**without** /ɡ/)

You could even with a little imagination use them both in the same sentence, and nobody would probly notice.

- *That "longer for justice" who was creating the commotion is no longer here.*

Comment: I do not understand. Aren't the words long pronounced the same way in both?

Comment: So, it depends on the suffix. If it's the comparative -er, then the pronunciation returns the /g/ to the word, but if it was the agentive -er, then the word will stay without the /g/.

this makes me think, does utterance-final /ŋɡ/ exist in English? (Utterance-final as in the speaker doesn't say anymore words after it)

Comment: That's exactly the thought many people had; the problem is that it's just a ghost of a /ɡ/, which velarizes the nasal -- it would otherwise be an /n/ -- without showing up except in certain (very specific) contexts. Much the same can be of /mb/ finals: _plumber_ is another agentive with no stop, only a labialized nasal. But _number_, which ought to rhyme, doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, yes.

I know nothing of phonetics but the difference is between 'long ass' and 'long gas' with the emphasis for some reason on 'long' in the first case and 'gas' in the second.

Does that not say it all?

Comment: I think he's asking about folks who pronounce *Long Island* kinda like *lawn guy land*, versus those who don't.

Comment: @tchrist I don't doubt that and while it might restrict the depth or range, I don't see that it changes the principle.